# Pass Expression Value to JavaScript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, expression

I have this following code, here `CssClass` is of the String type.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" title="<%# Title %>" class="<%# CssClass %>">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Style="padding-top: 20px; color: Red">
    Invalid Credential
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="text-align: center; padding-top: 50px;">
    <telerik:RadButton ID="LoginFaild" runat="server" Text="Ok" Font-Size="14px" Width="100px"
        OnClientClicked='<%# "function(button, args){closeDialog(" + CssClass + ");}" %>' />
</asp:Panel>
```

Now I want to pass this String value to the JavaScript function `closeDialog()` which is:

```
var closeDialog = function (className) {    
    $("." + className).dialog("close");
}
```

When I am clicking on the button I am getting

> loginError is not defined

in my Web Developer's Toolbar of Firefox.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that CssClass is set in c#, you do not need to specify the inline CssClass property in the close dialog constructor.  Change your closeDialog function to:

```
var closeDialog = function () {    
    $("." + <%= CssClass %>).dialog("close");
}
```

Then your OnClientClicked event can be rewritten as:

```
OnClientClicked="function(button, args){ closeDialog(); };" or OnClientClicked="closeDialog();"
```

**EDIT:**

Script at the Top of the Page

```
var cssClass = '<%= CssClass %>';
```

Close Dialog Function

```
var closeDialog = function () {    
    $("." + cssClass).dialog("close");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But actually the `closeDialog()` is in a JS file and I would be able to put it is aspx page, since this method will going to be used in various different places.

Comment: Ok. Instead of having the script block inside the function, you could set a javascript variable 'cssClass' at the top of your aspx page and then use this variable in the function.  I've edited my answer.